# google.maps.Polyline (JavaScript API) "path" property does not get initialized

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I am receiving some sort of weird behavior from google.maps.Polyline class in JavaScript API of Google Maps.

What I am trying to achieve is simple - to draw a Polyline on a map from continuously updated Array of LatLngLiteral's.

The problem - **the "path" property of google.maps.Polyline does not get initialized** and therefore Polyline is not visible. The weird part is that regardless of the fact that I include "path" property in initialization of google.maps.Polyline, **after the map is loaded, such property does not exist** (although Polyline object is created and I can access other properties of it).

The precise error I get: "*Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at ok (map.js:74)*". I tried setting a value of "path" via setPath() method, I tried using LatLng classes, tried MVCArray class - nothing works. Thanks in advance for your assistance! The code is below. (the code below is not optimized, I'm just starting on basic functionality for this project)

```
function loadMap(){
    var options = {
        zoom : 15,
        center : {lat:42.553080288955805, lng: 11.25}                               
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("test-map"),options);
    player  = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                map: map,
                position: {lat:42.553080288955805, lng: 11.25},
                title: "This is you!",
                label: {
                    text: "You are here!",
                    color: "rgb(50,50,255)",
                    fontFamily: "Helvetica, sans-serif",
                    fontWeight: "bold"
                }
            });

    //initializing path variable
    pathArray = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-42, 11), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(-43, 12), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(-44, 15)
    ];
    playerPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        path: pathArray, //the value here is not assigned for some reason
        strokeColor: "orange", //this property and value is assigned and 
                               //accessible after the map was loaded
        visible: true
    });

}

let options2 = {
        enableHighAccuracy : true,
        timeout : 10000,
        maximumAge : 30000
    };


var positionWatcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(ok,null,options2);
function ok(p){
    player.setPosition({lat:p.coords.latitude, lng:p.coords.longitude}); // works ok
    playerPath.path.push({lat:p.coords.latitude, lng:p.coords.longitude});
//above line provides the mentioned error
}
```

Comment: Sure, no problem, please have a look if it's more readable now.

Answer (score 0):

As there were no replies on this, I dug deep and found a working solution, however the question why *"path"* property of this object is not created during Polyline instance creation is still puzzling me.

In any case, it appears that *"path"* property only accepts **google.maps.MVCArray([LatLng, LatLng])** as a value during the initialization. The JavaScript API says it should accept a regular Array object with either LatLng or LatLngLiteral as elements, but it doesn't (at least in my code, which is quite straightforward).

So if you have the same issue, I suggest initializing path like this:

```
pathArray = new google.maps.MVCArray([
        new google.maps.LatLng(-42, 11), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(-43, 12), 
        new google.maps.LatLng(-44, 15)
    ]);

    playerPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        path: pathArray
    });
```